Custom color in .sty file
I have a .sty file that changes the chapter header. I want to be able to use my custom color in this file, however I always get an error no matter where I put it. I already tried putting it in the .tex file of the document I'm working in, the .sty file itself and the .cfg and .cls files of the document type I'm using. Where do I need to put this command in order to make it work?
\definecolor{mycolor}{cmyk}{0.6,0.3,0,0}



\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2001/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{kulemtx}
    [2010/02/28 v0.1
     Additions to the kulemt document class]
\newsavebox\kulemtx@chpnumbox
\def\kulemtx@buildchpnum#1#2{\sbox\kulemtx@chpnumbox{%
    \tabular[t]{@{}c@{}}%
      \makebox[0pt][c]{\chapnamefont #1\strut}\\[.5ex]%
      \colorbox[mycolor]{.8}{\color{black}%
        \rule[-7em]{0pt}{0pt}%
        {\chapnumfont \hspace{.7ex}#2\hspace{.7ex}\strut}}%
    \endtabular}}


An option is to place \usepackage{xcolor} before \usepackage{kulemtx} so that the command \definecolor is defined.
Another option is to use
\ProvidesPackage{...}[...]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{...}{...}{...}

in the .sty file.

Thank you very much for answer, but this is not what caused the error. The error came from the fact that I didn't understand the syntax of the \colorbox command. Just changing the command to \colorbox[cmyk]{0.6,0.3,0,0}{...} or \colorbox{mycolor}{...} solved the problem.
